# returning a String with X repeated characters without a loop

Tags: java, string

I stuck a little. I have a method, which should return a new String contains X times repeated character "y". X and Y are arguments of method. So, simple solution wiil be like this:

```
public String someMethod(int x,char y){
    String result="";
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++) result+=y;
    return result;    
}
```

And I've tried to figure out, is there any way to do the same just in one line, without looping. For example:

```
public String someMethod(int x,char y){
    return new StringBuilder().append('y', x);    
}
```

But there isn't such method for StringBuilder or StringBuffer or etc. Can you give me any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**
So, the solution will be:

```
public String someMethod(int x,char y){
    return new String(new char[x]).replace("\0", String.valueOf(y))  
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Any reason why it has to be done without a loop? Any built-in function, if it were to exist, most likely uses a loop anyway.

Comment: Just for simplifying (making code more compact).

Comment: Not a good reason, use loop instead.

Comment: If I would look at your code, I would start thinking like "what is s/he trying to achieve", soon followed by "Why no loop? There must be a reason for it".
If you would just use a loop (while avoiding concatenation - use StringBuilder), it's obvious what you are trying to do, and it's the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Here we are generating a new `char[]` which default initializes to all `0`'s, and then replacing these `0`'s with the character we want.

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int x = 5;
        String y = "h";
        String result = new String(new char[x]).replace("\0", y);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3523579, I just updated it to use a variable instead of a literal, but it's the same thing.

Comment: There is more simple than that: create a `char[]` and use `Arrays.fill()`

Comment: @fge, `Arrays.fill()` returns `void` so that would require at least three lines (one to declare the `char[]`, one to fill it, and one to make a string out of it), where my solution requires one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public String someMethod(int x,char y){
    char[] a = new char[x];
    Arrays.fill(a, 0, x, y);
    return new String(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others are saying, it's not possible completely without a loop - you could hide it behind other methods, but they still use a loop.

If it's just for the sake of "more compact" code, you could write your own method to do exactly that - or you use third party libs like Apache Commons StringUtils : `StringUtils.repeat(String str, int repeat)` should do the job

[Javadoc for `StringUtils.repeat(...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question almost 5 years later.

In Java 11 it can be done as following:

```
public String someMethod(int x, char y) {
    return String.valueOf(y).repeat(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuffer & loop, without loop this can't be done.
Even you found a method that could do it without loop, inside it's still use loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String someMethod(int x,char y) {
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    return someMethod( x, y, buff );
}

public String someMethod(int x,char y, StringBuilder buff) {
    if (x == 0) return buff.toString();
    else {
        buff.append( y );
        return someMethod( x, y, buff );
    }
}
```

...but recursion is not better than loop if this is not a puzzle...

On the other hand, recursion is more general, when someone wants to remove loop comparing to some String realted functions (in this case `new String(char[])` and `replace()`)

Answer (score 0):

For java 8 you could use a stream:

```
Stream.generate(() -> String.valueOf(y))
      .limit(x)
      .collect(Collectors.joining()).toString()
```